# Python - static interface for hardware IO

Tags: python, python-2.7, static-methods, gpio, static-class

This a somewhat general question so forgive me if I'm breaking any guidelines.
I'm writing a JQuery / websocket / Flask application that uses a Raspberry Pi to monitor some sensors as well as manage some active hardware.  Multiple classes and objects spawned by my Flask-implemented server need to be able to access my hardware.

Based off my programming background (relatively new to Python) I would gravitate to a static class with class methods that operate without instantiation.

I've found documentation on how to do that in Python but I'm not sure it's the best approach.  Is it more Pythonic to instantiate an object and pass it around or ... ?

Here is the non-static object oriented code I'm using now (I'm thinking a static version of the following will suite my needs but I want to do what is most appropriate for the language):

```
import os
import glob
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

#class to manage hardware -- sensors, pumps, etc
class Hardware:

    #system params for sensor
    os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
    os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

    #global vars for sensor 
    base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
    device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
    device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

    #global var for program
    temp_unit = 'F' #temperature unit, choose C for Celcius or F for F for Farenheit
    temp_target = 69 #target temperature to cool to in chosen unit
    temp_log_loc = '/var/www/hw-log.csv' #location of temp log, by default Raspberry Pi Apache server
    gpio_pin = 17 

    #function to enable GPIO
    def gpio_active(self,active):
        if active is True:
            GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
            GPIO.setup(self.gpio_pin, GPIO.OUT)
        else:
            GPIO.cleanup() 

    #def __init__(self): Not used

    #reads raw temp from sensor
    def read_temp_raw(self):
        f = open(self.device_file, 'r')
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        return lines

    #cleans up raw sensor data, returns temp in unit of choice
    def read_temp(self):
        lines = self.read_temp_raw()
        while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
            time.sleep(0.2)
            lines = self.read_temp_raw()
        equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
        if equals_pos != -1:
            temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
            temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
            temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
        if self.temp_unit == 'F':
            return temp_f
        else:
            return temp_c

#**********sensors**********

    #mashtun sensor
    #@staticmethod
    def mashtun_temp(self):
        return self.read_temp()

    #hot liquor tank sensor
    def htl_temp(self):
        return 200

    #fermentor sensor
    def fermentor_temp(self):
        return 65

#**********pumps**********
    def herms_pump_active(self,active):
        self.gpio_active(True)
        if active is True:
            print('***Hardware report: Setting HERMS pump on***')
            GPIO.output(self.gpio_pin,GPIO.LOW)
        else:
            print('Setting HERMS pump off')
            GPIO.output(self.gpio_pin,GPIO.HIGH)
        self.gpio_active(False)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't match the description; none of those are class methods.

Comment: Sorry to be unclear -- that's the code I'm using now.
I want a static version of that, if that is in fact an appropriate and Pythonic approach.

Comment: Don't `modprobe` at the class level. That code is run when the module is loaded which would be bad if you had a script that loaded the module for other reasons. And what if the modprobe failed? This seems like a good case for a factory function that creates an instance on first access and then keeps handing that back to callers.

Comment: So I would instantiate the Hardware class and then have a method that returns itself to requestors?